# How dpkg check config files when upgrading packages

Tags: debian, dpkg, deb

I'm building .deb packages for my internal tools. 
And would like to find a right way how to deal with configuration files on upgrade.

Currently when I install package-0.2.deb over package-0.1.deb, using `apt install ./package-0.2.deb` it replaces my existing configuration files in `/etc/package/*`

Instead, I would like to ask user what to do with old modified conf file (Replace, Keep, etc., like it works e.g. in nginx) by adding `postinst` or `preinst` control files. But can't find a common way how to do it other package maintainers.

Package dir structure

`/DEBIAN/control
/etc/package/package.conf
/usr/bin/package`

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles
https://wiki.debian.org/DpkgConffileHandling
https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/

Comment: So, as I can see here https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles
`dh_installdeb(1) automatically flags any files under the /etc directory as conffiles`
But actually it doesn't.. I will try to specify it manually in conffiles.

Comment: The fact that your `/DEBIAN` folder is in all caps tells me that you are probably manually building a binary package?  That would mean that the standard tools that automatically do things like flag things don't happen.  The more Debian way of doing thigns is to build from a source package.

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, I'm using dpkg-deb --build to build .deb package from my binaries and conf files.
So, I should manualy create DEBIAN/conffiles in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI
To be asked by installer what to do with old configuration files, those files must be listed in /DEBIAN/conffiles file